# GetGeopositionAsync hanging in windows phone 8 when used in ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, geolocation

Can someone please put me in the right direction here, as I'm totally confused as to why when I call GetGeopositionAsync from my ViewModel, it hangs but when called from my view it works ok?

Here is the code that works:

```
private async void btnLocate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this._geolocator.LocationStatus != PositionStatus.Disabled && this._geolocator.LocationStatus != PositionStatus.NotAvailable)
    {
        try
        {
            this._geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 5;
            Geoposition position = await this._geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
            Geocoordinate geocoordinate = position.Coordinate;
            this.mapWithMyLocation.Center = CoordinateConverter.ConvertGeocoordinate(geocoordinate);
        }
        catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
public class LocationEntryViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    async public Task<GeoCoordinate> GetMyLocation()
    {
        if (this._geolocator.LocationStatus != PositionStatus.Disabled && this._geolocator.LocationStatus != PositionStatus.NotAvailable)
        {
            try
            {
                this._geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 5;
                Geoposition position = await this._geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();                    
                Geocoordinate geocoordinate = position.Coordinate;
                return CoordinateConverter.ConvertGeocoordinate(geocoordinate);
            }
            catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                throw;
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new GeoCoordinate();
        }
    }

    public void SetMyLocation()
    {
        this.MyLocation = GetMyLocation().Result;
    }
}
```

And then I call this from my View

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        _locationEntryViewModel.SetMyLocation();
    }
```

I've read in an article, which I can no longer find, that I should not initialize this from the constructor of my ViewModel, so for testing purpose I put in in OnNavigateTo instead but if there is a way to do this, please let me know as I feel it would make more sense, no??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The **.Result** call is causing deadlock because the GetMyLocation method wants to continue running on UI thread at the same time, when you are waiting for the Result on UI thread.

For solving this just change the SetMyLocation method to be async and use it like this:

```
public async Task SetMyLocation()
{
    this.MyLocation = await GetMyLocation();
}
```

And on the place, where you are calling SetMyLocation, use await as well.

Comment: That didn't work. I've made the changes you suggested and added async to OnNavigatedTo where my viewmodel is called from, but still hangs. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are calling `Result` in the UI thread, thus [causing a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I explain in full on my blog.

To fix this, you should use a type like the [`NotifyTaskCompletion` type in my AsyncEx library](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NotifyTaskCompletion&referringTitle=Documentation) to provide property change events when tasks complete. It's fine to kick off this kind of initialization in your constructor.

```
public class LocationEntryViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
  public INotifyTaskCompletion<GeoCoordinate> MyLocation { get; private set; }

  public LocationEntryViewModel()
  {
    MyLocation = NotifyTaskCompletion.Create(GetMyLocation());
  }
}
```

Then your data binding can use paths like `MyLocation.Result`. Note that this is `null` until `GetMyLocation` completes. If you want a different UI (e.g., spinner or whatnot), you can data bind to `MyLocation.IsCompleted`. Also, if you want to data bind your exceptions, you can use `MyLocation.ErrorMessage`. Other convenience properties are available.

For more information, see my [`async` properties blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html).